# Robots.txt for WordPress when not in root directory

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt

If the WP install is not in the root (lets say it’s in /newsite/ like in http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory ) where does the robots.txt file go (root or instal folder) and what are the paths to be:

```
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/

OR

Disallow: newsite/wp-admin/
Disallow: newsite/wp-includes/
Disallow: newsite/wp-content/plugins/
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, your Site is reachable under **www.example.com** under the directory `/var/www/` and your WordPress-Blog is under `/var/www/newsite/`, than put the **robots.txt** in `/var/www/` and change the folders in there:

```
 Disallow: /newsite/wp-admin/
 Disallow: /newsite/wp-includes/
 Disallow: /newsite/wp-content/plugins/
```

Why `/newsite/wp-admin/` and not `/var/www/newsite/wp-admin/` for example?
The directory is relative from the URI like **http://www.example.com/newsite/**

Comment: Thank you. So it's newsite/wp-admin and not just /wp-admin/ right? I understand this now :D thanks a lot. But please can you confirm?

Comment: Haha, thanks a lot for your help. I appreciate it. But why so angry :) I can read. Thanks again. Great help!

Answer (score 1):

robots.txt need to be always accessible from the root of your domain e.g.:

`http://www.example.de/robots.txt`

[W3C docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.4.1.1)